# @font-face and -webkit-transform: rotate, doesn't work

Tags: css, webkit, font-face

I'm making a website with HTML5 and CSS3 features. I've got two custom fonts which are added through @font-face. They're used in logo. They're in 'h1' tags, and I rotated them with CSS3 proporety:

```
transform: rotate(350deg);
```

Of course for every browser I used proper prefix (for IE: "-ms-", for FF: "-moz-", for Chrome/Safari: "-webkit-" and for Opera: "-o-"). The problem is that it doesn't rotate in Chrome and Safari. So my question is, does Webkit engine allow to rotate custom fonts with CSS3 properties?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most inline content doesn't support transforms in webkit browsers - this is a known limitation. Although H1 is a block level tag, my guess is that you're using a span tag (inline) inside the H1 tag around your actual text to add the font, and this is giving you problems.

Add "display: inline-block" and see if that helps.

Comment: Yep, I'm using <span> tags and yes your suggestion helped. Thanks a lot.